# Anyone know of good online guides for the Multi-player maps for MW2

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-2

Just looking for good online guides for MW2 and if possible guides about the range of MW2 multi-player maps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This guy has a [YouTube series](http://www.youtube.com/user/SAM5000i) called Map Attack when he gives out tips and tricks about some of the maps in MW2.

Answer (score 1):

i thought this ( http://www.nextgentactics.com/Games.aspx?Area=1&GName=Call%20of%20Duty%20Modern%20Warfare%202%20Multiplayer ) particularly good.